# Description of the norm of certain interpolation space 

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Dear all,

I suspect that there should be some detailed description of the norm (or of the unit ball) of the following complex interpolation space (for any $0< \theta < 1$): $$\Big(B(\ell_1^n, \ell_2^n), B(\ell_\infty^n, \ell_2^n)\Big)_\theta.$$

Where $B(\ell_1^n, \ell_2^n)$ stands for the space of bounded linear operators from $\ell_1^n$ to $\ell_2^n$. Here $n$ is the dimension, which is assumed to be abitrary.

Does anyone know some reference for this?

Thank you!